# Installer fails to launch on Mid-2010 iMAC (27 inch) - error message, then black screen

Tags: system-installation

(I've gone through the past posts and haven't found anyone who lists this same issue.)

I have a mid-2010 iMAC still running OSX that I want to switch to Elementary OS for faster performance. I've downloaded Elementary OS, verified Checksum, created a boot drive on a memory stick, and when I restart computer with Option held down, I get options for : Macintosh HD, REcovery, EFI Boot, and EFI Boot. I've tried both the EFI Boot options and the screen goes black and the below error message flashes briefly, then the screen goes black again:

[0.440561] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0" Found HC with no IRQ. Check BIOS/PCI 0000:00:1a.0 setup!
[0.440576] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: init 0000:00:1a.0 fail, -19
and 2 more lines of similar errors.

Any idea what is going on? I would think the computer is not compatible but I've verified it is 64Bit, etc.  Seems like multiple people have used similar era Macs.   Could use some help as would really like to use Elementary OS for this machine.

More info:
I just tried installing Ubantu.  It did give an error but the boot menu came up with this installer.  When I chose the first option, it played music but was black screened.  I assumed that the monitor wasn't working.  So, second time I chose "Ubantu with Safe Graphics" and I saw the EXACT SAME "uhci-hcd" errors as with the Elementary OS install!!!  But then the launch menu came up.

Does this indicate that it is something to do with with the integrated monitor on my computer?   Is there a way to simulate a "SAFE Graphics" launch with Elementary OS?

Comment: So, the monitor works fine if I connect an external monitor and reboot.  It's bizarre because only the iMAC monitor works but I have to have the external monitor plugged when I boot for the iMAC monitor to work.  It must be something about the drivers.   Any advice on how to load a driver that will fix this issue????

Comment: There is some weirdness involving the graphics subsystem on Macs of that era. While the video card is an ATI, it’s a heavily customized one that was only ever used on iMacs 

Comment: Hm, so it's just not possible to run with this setup?  I saw at least one person who claimed they installed the driver from AMD's website and it fixed the issue.   How does one install a proprietary driver with Elementary OS?  I've run some searches and tried some methods but no joy.

Comment: I do not have a 2010-era iMac to test this with, but people have generally been able to resolve this by using rEFInd, which sits between Apple’s secret sauce and the Linux kernel. With this layer sitting between the hardware and software, the video subsystem tends to work decently. However, as I have mentioned, I don’t have hardware here to test with 